# Zend Tool create action does not recognise controller in module

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a module and controller using:

```
$ zf create module api
$ zf create controller auth index-action-included=1 api
```

This works fine, and I get the index action when I request `http://localhost/api/auth`.

I want to create a new action called validate:

```
$ zf create action validate auth view-included=1 api
```

But I get told that:

```
An Error Has Occurred                         
Controller auth was not found.
```

Edit:

I have directly added the action in the controller, and created the view file - but I hope I don't miss anything else I need here that the command line should have created.

Comment: I recommended make double check of .zfproject.xml file in your project folder and ensure that there no typo error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command should be like this:

```
$ zf create action validate -c auth
```

For details [zend commands](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.usage.cli.html)

Comment: hmm.. would help if the command line help also indicated that - but what happens if you have an auth controller in two different modules?

Comment: it also seems to put the view in the application directory rather than the module... back to manual editing for the now

Comment: @HorusKol: If you see the details link which i put in the answer, you will find the details to your query

Comment: I did look at that link - there is one sentence saying that this create action command creates an action, and three variations of the same command... nothing about different modules, and nothing about the view not being put in the module directory

Comment: Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.11.10 still has only this way, while it suggests the following syntax (that's not working):
zf create action name controller-name[=Index] view-included[=1] module

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem:

```
zf create controller Account
...
zf create action list Account
An Error Has Occurred                         
Controller Account was not found.
```

The cause seems to be that `create controller` command doesn't add section into  of the .zfproject file:

```
  <controllersDirectory>
    <controllerFile controllerName="Index">
      <actionMethod actionName="index"/>
    </controllerFile>
    <controllerFile controllerName="Error"/>
  </controllersDirectory>
```

Workaround: I added manually `<controllerFile controllerName="Account">`

```
  <controllersDirectory>
    <controllerFile controllerName="Index">
      <actionMethod actionName="index"/>
    </controllerFile>
    <controllerFile controllerName="Account">
      <actionMethod actionName="index"/>
    </controllerFile>
    <controllerFile controllerName="Error"/>
  </controllersDirectory>
```

After this `zf create action list Account` was executed successfully.

Comment: zf create controller Account default

actually does create xml file controller entry (default means without a module), but it still didn't help me creating an action.